# latex shell for article style svjour3

Tags: templates, scientific-workplace

Does anyone have/is willing to send me/can point me to a latex shell file in Scientific Workplace 5.0 (or maybe 5.5 or 6.0) for the style svjour3, from Springer?

I'm writing the (math) paper in swp 5.0, which is old enough (2004) only to have the shell svjour. And I've tried downloading the appropriate files from Springer, to my complete bafflement.

Thanks very much.

Comment: The MacKichan Software site https://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/shells/710.htm~mainFrame has svjour3 listed as an available shell.

Comment: Thanks, Cicada.